# How do I add a button click event on a different class in .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am newbie with asp.net MVC and i want something simple. I have an `Index.aspx` page and a `UrlContent.cs` class.

I am searching how to write the code of the `button_click` listener of the page in the class. So far havent found anything on google.

Thats all, thank you

Comment: If you want a `button_click` handler wired from a `aspx` pages to a `.cs` you need [Webforms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) not MVC.... otherwise I highly recommend you to start on MVC with http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC is a different paradigm, and doesn't really have the concept of "event listeners".

That concept was always an abstraction from how web clients/servers really communicated.  To a web server, there's really only one event, and that is an HTTP request from the client.  To achieve the illusion of "events", ASP.Net does some (Javascript+cookies) magic behind the scenes, and creates hidden form `input` tags -- containing info about which button was clicked -- within a standard HTML form, and posting the form back to the server.

MVC adheres much more closely to the native behavior of HTML/HTTP.  It requires you to get accustomed to working with those technologies -- forms, GET/POST requests, and AJAX.

---

To handle a (submit form) button click event, you create an action in your controller that accepts parameters.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    // handle the submit button's "click event" here
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")) {
    @Html.EditorForModel
    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's exactly what i was searching for

Answer (score 0):

If you're running MVC, I think you're looking for something like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action method Name", "Controller name",new {} , new {})
```

[Here's some documentation on more overloads.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040%28v=vs.108%29)